# RSA encryption for radio waves

Tags: digital-communications

Usually RSA encryption is used for internet security.
What are these disadvantages if we want to use RSA encryption to secure a radio communication?

Comment: Can you please *edit your question* to clarify what you mean by "radio _waves_".  Radio is used to send digital information (e.g. _Internet_), and RSA encryption works on digital information just fine -- so RSA works on information _sent out over the radio_ just fine, too.  So it's unclear what you think is special about a radio _wave_ that makes it not suitable for RSA.

Answer (score 1):

> Usually RSA encryption is used for internet security.

Your claim is not quite right, no. RSA is used in *a lot* of places, and it's not exclusive, maybe not even dominantly used for internet transport encryption. But the RSA cryptosystem was invented 1977; not that much concern with the internet back then, and common places where you find RSA today is banking card authentication and security, RFID passports, authenticity of new USB standards, physical entry control (key) cards, and a lot of places where cryptography meets actual physical safety. And, of course, some modes of TLS, PGP etc, but in these internet-style applications it's often being phased out.

As a matter of fact, on the internet, it's practically only used for *key exchange*, not for payload encryption. You used the Public/Private Key pair to establish a channel which you use to exchange a symmetrical key, which usually makes cryptography much faster.

> What are these disadvantages if we want to use RSA encryption to secure a radio communication?

We can't talk about "disadvantages" without specifying "compared to what"; that's just like asking "Is that mountain steeper?" without specifying compared to which other mountain.

From the top of my head, I can't find anything where RSA would be worse than any other comparable system in a wireless channel. Information-theoretically, it's a necessity that bit flips break your communication significantly, so the bit-error-proneness is a problem for *all* similar methods.

So, unless you specify "disadvantageous" very precisely in terms of some aspect of your system, and you specify them as a relationship to something else, your question will be inanswerable or answered only with "None".